# One of Elastic Beanstalk IP Addresses is not accessible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

So I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment with Application Load Balancer and Auto Scale Group.

A VPC has 1 public subnet & 2 private subnets

The EC2 Instances is running inside the private subnets of my VPC. (Current only 1 instance is running)

The Load Balancer is running in all of the public & private subnets of my VPC.

Everything is working. But it seems like the Elastic Beanstalk domain has multiple IP Addresses (which is as I know correct). But **one of them is not accessible**.

I'm not sure why. But is it because the IP is the private IP of the EC2 Instance?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Which LB, ALB? It has nodes in 2 AZs. Are your instances in the two 2 AZs? Also ifs its ALB, you shoudn't be using its IPs. They are not static.

Comment: Yes. I'm using Application Load Balancer

Comment: Check where are your instances, or your subnets. ALB can only route traffic to AZs it was setup with.

Comment: @Marcin So my ALB is setup with 3AZs (a b c), my instances are running in `b` and `c`

Comment: When you use ALB dns, it all works correctly?

Comment: Sometimes it works correctly. But sometimes, it takes too much time for `Initial Connection` ~1 minute. So I guess it's because of the one of the IPs is not accessible.

Comment: But if you have only 1 public subnet, how ALB can be in two AZs?

Comment: `Assign your load balancer to a subnet in each Availability Zone (AZ) in which your application runs`

I assigned it with the AZs that instances are running in. 

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but ALB should be in public subnets. So you should have 2 public subnets, one in each AZ for your ALB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216120/discussion-between-tan-dat-and-marcin).

Comment: @Marcin thank you. Please add to answer below if you want :D

Comment: Thank you. Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue caused due to the fact that ALB was placed in two AZs: 1 public and **1 private**. Subsequent, the ALB node in the private node was not publicly accessible.

The **solution** was to put the ALB in only **public subnets**.